# Run Bash Command At X Time and Terminate for X Time

Tags: c, linux, bash

Hi im working on a simple bash coding i don't know how to accomplish this and this might be easy for you guys please help.

I have a simple program on file.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

./program
```

This ./program is a compiled version of C program which i complied using GCC im trying to use at in bash script to execute this program for few seconds and then terminate that after x interval time and restart again.

**I hope you got my point?**

Example: Run file.sh for 10 sec and I'll display the result from ./program C program and then after 10 sec it will restart again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, if I understand correctly, a combination of `sleep` and `timout`:

```
while :; do
    timout 10s ./program
    # display some results
    sleep 10
done
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! What dose actually sleep 10 doing here?

Comment: @Noor For most UNIX commands, use `man` to get documentation e.g. `man sleep` and `man timeout`. Sometimes it doesn't work because the command is a shell built-in. Then look for it in `man bash`, `info bash` or the bash documentation on the web.

Comment: You asked, that after 10 seconds, the program should start again. So after the program is terminated, the script sleeps 10 seconds.

Comment: This solved the issue thanks anyway! I marked as solved!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sleep` command. For example: `exec ./program && sleep n` where n is the time you want the command to sleep. If you want you could put it in a while loop inside an `sh` script and run it continuously.

To run it continuously until you close the terminal:

```
while true
do
   echo "[CTRL+C] to stop..."
   timeout 10s ./program
done
```

Comment: Doesn't 'exec ./program && sleep 10' work? If I understood your question it should do the trick

Comment: When it executed terminal got closed instantly: exec ./program && sleep 10

Comment: Try removing the exec. Also, does your program run as expected on its own?

Comment: Nope didn't work nothing happened. And to close program i have to manually press CTRL + C to close it.. I wanna set time interval so it loads few seconds and terminate and then restart again like a loop until i close the terminal i hope you understand my point right?

Comment: Then try './program ;; sleep 10 && ./program'. Let me know if it works

Comment: didn't work either.. ./file.sh && sleep 10 && ./file.sh i try that with 2 sec still no hope.

Comment: Ok. How about 'timeout 10s ./program && timeout 10s ./program'?

Comment: Yes it terminated after 10 secs but && didn't work and one more thing i wanna run that bash code for 10 sec then terminate and restart in loop until i close the terminal to stop that..